# spring security oauth2 returning 404 after authorize

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have setup `OAuth2` client application with the following configuration in my `application.yml` file

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          octa:
            client-id: <confidential>
            client-secret: <confidential>
            scope: openid
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8555/oauth/callback
            clientName: octa
            provider: octa
        provider:
          octa:
            issuer-uri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default
            user-name-atttibute: name
server:
  port: 8555
```

My spring boot application is running on port `8555` and below is my security configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**","/callback/", "/webjars/**", "/error**", "/oauth/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

When the authorization server returns the url `http://localhost:8555/oauth/callback?code=t8oJIWdR2lTgY1_06WPzR2d` with `404` error.
I should ideally be getting the `access token`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Unless you have special logic for `/oauth/callback`, it seems you are running into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67890304/spring-oauth-2-0-client-returns-401-unauthorized-after-entering-correct-credenti/68002157#68002157